# bash variable array names and getting values

Tags: bash, scripts

As you see , i have situation to read values in different arrays, like array1 , array 2 , array3 etc.

and I need to print values `array1[0]`, `array2[1]`, like this.

I can do it individually like this `echo ${array1[0]}`

But, not able to get the way out here, can some one help.

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=(w1 w2 w3)
x=1
var=array$x[@]
echo ${!var}
echo ${array1[0]}
array2=(w4 w5 w6)
x=2
var=array$x[@]
echo ${!var}
```

Comment: Don't quite understand what the problem is. You've already demonstrated how to do this with indirect expansion: create a variable name (`var` here) and then call it with `${!var}`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a single element from the array, just use the same trick as for the whole array:

```
var=array$x[1]
echo ${!var}
```